# How to add an eventlistener on specific field of a database

Tags: javascript, php, database, codeigniter, event-listener

Is there a way for my controller to add eventlistener on a specific field | table ?

Basically i would like to execute some instructions( in the controller side ) as soon as the field in my table changes value, without using loop such as :

```
while(!field) { sleep(5) ; field = request_field_from_db(); }
```

I m using Codeigniter as a framework if that helps